# How to hook up jasmin-node expectations and matchers with cucumber.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, bdd, jasmine

I'm like to use one testing language (assertions and matchers) to do both unit and BDD/functional test. i.e.

```
stepDefinitions = ->
  @World = require("../support/world").World

  @Given /^I visit the website$/, (cb) ->
    (@visit 'http://localhost:3000', cb)

  @Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"'s homepage$/, (title, cb) ->
    (expect @browser.html()).not.toBeNull()
    cb?()

module.exports = stepDefinitions
```

requiring jasmine-node isn't cutting, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this previously too. One should extract the expect/matchers mechanism. I've had a quick look at it and it's not a trivial thing to do, I'm afraid.

There are some packages (e.g. [expectations](https://npmjs.org/package/expectations)) on NPM that offer expect-like syntax but I haven't found something good enough just yet.

You might consider Node.js's standard [assertion library](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/assert.html) too.

Comment: Yeah. Started of like that. Now I'm using Chai. it's very close.